# How do I get bjam to set include paths for OpenSSL headers and libraries on MSVC?

Tags: visual-c++, openssl, bjam

I'm trying to add code that uses OpenSSL to my bjam based program on MSVC, but I can't figure out how to get the include paths for OpenSSL added (without hard-coding the directory, which would only work on my machine). What I'm asking, is how to get bjam to search the set of system include paths. In CMake this would be done using find_package. What's the "standard" way for bjam?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to change include path using bjam](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3390648) and/or  [How can I get bjam to find my .h files in other directories](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12290965), but I'm not a bjam expert. Maybe you could detail the problem a little more.

Comment: Yeah, this is not the same thing. I know how to manually add include paths to the Jamfile.v2, using " <location>". But manually specifying the path to OpenSSL would be "hard-coding the directory, which would only work on my machine" (see question). What I'm asking, is how to get bjam to search the set of system include paths. In CMake this would be done using find_package.

Comment: I think your explanation makes for a better title and question. You might consider editing the question. You might also consider adding your tool chain, like Visual Studio or [VC++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools). Finally, Windows is not like Unix, and there is no standard include directory (`/usr`) or alternate directory (`/usr/local`, `/opt/local`, etc). Depending on you tool chain, there may be an `INCLUDE` environmental variable (along with some others, like `LIB`). I'm guessing this is going to be a standard Unix-Windows disconnect by Bjam.